# Getting git changes from one directory into another as a separate branch

Tags: git

We are working with a contractor that cannot access our git repo hosted internally. The temp way around this while we wait for IT is zipping up the repo, sending it to them, have them make a commit locally, then rezipping the repo and sending it back to us.

How do I go about making a separate branch containing only their changes in my local repo? Currently their changes are behind by 2 commmits.

my repo's `git log`

```
* ac72bef - (HEAD -> master, staging/master, production/master, origin/master, origin/HEAD) Add pre-rendered navbar (4 weeks ago)
* e156389 - Update release notes URL in Navbar (4 weeks ago)
* 5bd10fe - Change Lando's local server (7 weeks ago)
* 765207c - Blog: Add support link in footer (2 months ago)
* 2d7256d - Blog: Update enterprise support link in nav dropdown (3 months ago)
...
```

their repo's `git log`

```
* dd1db76 - (HEAD -> master) added series in posts, added author in header, responsive css (3 weeks ago)
* 5bd10fe - (staging/master, production/master, origin/master, origin/HEAD) Change Lando's local server (7 weeks ago)
* 765207c - Blog: Add support link in footer (2 months ago)
* 2d7256d - Blog: Update enterprise support link in nav dropdown (3 months ago)
```

where their changes are all in commit `dd1db76`

Ideally I want to achieve this in my own repo in a separate branch

```
* dd1db76 - (contractors-changes) added series in posts, added author in header, responsive css (3 weeks ago)
* ac72bef - (master, staging/master, production/master, origin/master, origin/HEAD) Add pre-rendered navbar (4 weeks ago)
* e156389 - Update release notes URL in Navbar (4 weeks ago)
* 5bd10fe - Change Lando's local server (7 weeks ago)
* 765207c - Blog: Add support link in footer (2 months ago)
* 2d7256d - Blog: Update enterprise support link in nav dropdown (3 months ago)
```

What are the steps to go about achieving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In their repo, set up yours as a remote and push to it. Instead of referencing it by URL, reference it by directory.

First, add your repository as a remote.

```
cd /path/to/contractor/repo
git remote add upstream /path/to/your/repo
```

Then make the branch in the contractor's repo and push it.

```
git co -b contractor-changes
git push upstream
```

Alternatively, you can skip making the branch and push their master directly to a new branch called ontractor-changes. But I find this is more difficult to keep track of.

```
git push upstream master:contractor-changes
```